# ExcelJS - Read Multiple worksheets in the same Excel

Tags: node.js, exceljs

I have 1 excel contains multiple sheets like below screenshot:

[image]

I am trying to read excel file using ExcelJS module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#exceljs

```
const Excel = require("exceljs");

const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

const filePath = `./test/CustomerData.xlsx`

workbook.xlsx.readFile(filePath)
    .then(function() {
    let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(0);
    console.log("Sheet name---", worksheet);            
});
```

It gives output as `Sheet name--- undefined` I want sheet names like:

```
Sheet name---CustomerData1
Sheet name---CustomerData2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getWorksheet uses an ID rather than an index. In the example below, I observed the ID field starting from 1. From the docs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#access-worksheets), the ID isn't guaranteed to start at 1, so you may want to loop through it like below:

```
const Excel = require("exceljs");
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
const filePath = `./test/CustomerData.xlsx`

workbook.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then(() => {
  console.log("Sheet name---", workbook.getWorksheet(1).name)
  console.log("Sheet name---", workbook.getWorksheet(2).name)

  workbook.worksheets.forEach((sheet, i) => {
    console.log("Array index:", i)
    console.log("exceljs id:", sheet.id)
    console.log("Sheet name---", sheet.name)
  })
});
```

My example produced the following:

```
Sheet name--- CustomerData1
Sheet name--- CustomerData2
Array index: 0
exceljs id: 1
Sheet name--- CustomerData1
Array index: 1
exceljs id: 2
Sheet name--- CustomerData2
```